# Assign variable from filter within template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, liquid

Im attempting to assign a variable returned from a filter to a variable inside a template. Is this even possible?

My filter:

```
def return_an_object(input)
  Model.find(input)
end
```

The liquid:

```
{% assign bar = {{ "foo" | return_an_object }} %}
```

This results in `input` being `nil` within `return_an_object`.

Is it at all possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this myself.

```
{% assign bar = {{ "foo" | return_an_object }} %}
```

Should be:

```
{% assign bar = "foo" | return_an_object %}
```